# a Div with higher z-index priority placing under a div containing flash

Tags: html, css

I designed a page that generates some DIV elements,
i defined z-index attribute in CSS to manage priority of elements
the problem is a div with a higher priority always fall behind and back of the Div element that contains flash swf object, what can i do the make flash element under other DIVes?

Comment: Does your Flash SWF `object` element happen to be absolutely positioned? (AKA `position: absolute;`)

Answer (score 1):

Ad this to the Flash embed code

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

ALso, ensure that both divs have postioning other than static (relative or absolute), or z-index won't work, but from your previous reply, I think you are doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Do the answers supplied by google not suffice?

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/keep-flash-behind-other-elements/